# BT LE support in official Android API

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am searching an official android API for BT LE  support in all BT LE Android devices.
The Motorola and Broadcom is supposed to have their own API for Bluetooth LE support but that is not affordable for other devices.
Can anybody tell me, is there any official Android API for BT LE support and if not then in with which version of Android will it be available

Answer (score 0):

don't know weather there will be an official support. But take a look at that [project](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/) at code.google

Comment: This is for the broadcom only.Will not do with othr devices

Answer (score 0):

The SDK 18 code has the Google API now.

The documentation is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

I am testing it and it is crashing on my Nexus 4, so not sure it is ready for primetime yet.